# Puzzling 404 error when attempting file export with Python SDK

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am attempting to export [a public file from Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/document/d/110vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo/edit?usp=sharing) to local drive using Google's python API client library.

I am using [this script](https://gist.github.com/aaronpolhamus/9df340f8bfbde4534ffe0523eb4b9a32), which is an adapted example of [this tutorial](http://wescpy.blogspot.mx/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html). I've verified that my credentials are working and have been working with `create` and `update` methods all day without any problem.

When I run `python api_demo.py` from the command line I get the expected result, with a PDF stored to my local drive:

```
aaronpolhamus$ python api_demo.py
  Uploaded "hello.txt" (text/plain)
  Uploaded "hello.txt" (application/vnd.google-apps.document)
  fileId: P110vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo
  mimeType: application/pdf
  Downloaded "hello.pdf" (application/pdf)
```

However, when I enter the python shell to work interactively I just *cannot* get this running. Here's how it looks:

```
In [1]: DRIVE.files().export(fileId='P110vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo', mimeType='application/pdf').execute()

/Users/aaronpolhamus/anaconda/envs/credijusto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
131                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
132                     logger.warning(message)
--> 133             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
134         return positional_wrapper
135 

/Users/aaronpolhamus/anaconda/envs/credijusto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
838       callback(resp)
839     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 840       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
841     return self.postproc(resp, content)
842 

HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/P110vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf returned "File not found: P110vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo.">
```

Now, the `fileId` doesn't actually have that leading `P1` if you go to the link. I tried chopping those first two characters off and wound up with a `500` error:

```
In [2]: DRIVE.files().export(fileId='10vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo', mimeType='application/pdf').execute()

HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-237-764cc68cfa0e> in <module>()
----> 1 DRIVE.files().export(fileId='10vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo', mimeType='application/pdf').execute()

/Users/aaronpolhamus/anaconda/envs/credijusto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
131                 elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
132                     logger.warning(message)
--> 133             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
134         return positional_wrapper
135 

/Users/aaronpolhamus/anaconda/envs/credijusto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
838       callback(resp)
839     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 840       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
841     return self.postproc(resp, content)
842 

HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/10vUov9J9rg2b1XoHMZ3Ssb4Z-FUUPKNQckuyxn_gmo/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf returned "Internal Error">
```

The difference between the command line and interactive cases are puzzling, as is the result that I can produce different errors but haven't gotten any closer to actually figuring out what's going on. I am doing the exact same operation, pasting in identical values to those printed in terminal.

Both code and sample data are public. Any help?

Comment: some suggestions...1) do you have any way to see the underlying http traffic, 2) for the 500, can you display the error message as well as the 500 status, 3) what is that P11 about - it's not a valid ID and would explain why you get a 404 not found. It might be something to do with URL escaping.

Comment: You were right--you have to take that leading "P" off and it's fine. No idea how that snuck in. I'm still not out of the woods yet, though, because I have some non-public sheets I am trying to manage via the API and am having the same difficulties. This `fileId` `1FCsDnhi54xsek7qng_MbLf4fh8DgYKqwbuBps2O8O_o` works fine on the SDK docs page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export. However the same command `data = DRIVE.files().export(fileId="1FCsDnhi54xsek7qng_MbLf4fh8DgYKqwbuBps2O8O_o", mimeType="text/csv").execute()` still returns `404 Not Found` in my local env.

Comment: I have a theory that I'm going to try out right now.

Comment: @pinoyyid OK, I worked something out. In the example I just mentioned in the comment, if I download the text from the original file and then re-upload the same file using the API SDK the new `fileId`. 

Really bewildered by this. It must have something to do with my local machine? I haven't followed your advice to check out the http traffic, yet--could have something to do with how I'm accessing the doc. Anyhow, thanks for the help.